# "Cron Not Running" system error after update to 4.7.1

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, 4.7

The detail is:
"No cron runs have been recorded."

Just updated from 4.6.10. This has never been a problem with other updates. What do I have to do to fix this? We need cron to send mailings as I recall.

Edit: **There are a lot of errors including "cron not running" on the civicrm wordpress demo site so it's not just me.** I think something needs a tidy.
Another error on the demo site:
"Failed to make directory (extensionsDir) at "/srv/buildkit/build/wpmaster/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/". Please update the settings or file permissions."

Answer (score 2):

I noticed on all my sites that I upgraded, it also initially had an error that cron was not running.  But after the first automatic cron run triggered by my host cron job, this went away.

Comment: How are you triggering cron?  PHP call, cURL, wget, wp-cli?

Comment: PHP to call cli.php

/usr/bin/php5 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u username -p password -e Job -a execute

Comment: So, you are using Drupal.  From what I've seen, this seems to be an issue with something being parsed in wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php and therefore is irrelevant to Drupal.  Sounds like Drupal might have a separate issue.

Comment: This is also happening in Joomla 3.4.8. Cronjob is running continuously without any errors in /var/log/cron

Comment: Using CLI, too:    nice -n19 /usr/bin/php-cli /home/account/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -j -s <site> -u <user> -p <password> -e Job -a execute >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: It appears that cli.php is completely broken now. With an alternative, I find that wp-cli reports that the process-mail-queue command is successful, but no bulk emails are sent out. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an issue with running php bin/cli.php. Can you try using wp-cli instead?

```
/path/to/wp --user=<cron> --url=<http://example.com> --path=</path/to/wp> civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hrm ... That's very interesting.  I'm fighting the same error, though it is persisting far beyond the first run.  On mine it seems like it's failing to render the WP_Error correctly.  I thought it was a third party plugin, but I'm beginning to feel like it is deeper.  Perhaps related to the removal of the "htmlize" class?  Here's a bug I've opened.  https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17981

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the Civi instructions on cron. I performed an adjustment of the permissions of ../civicrm/bin/cli.php from 0754 to 0755 and the error message disappeared.

See [Wrong permissions for cli.php](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs)

Comment: Unfortunately, despite the cronjob running and the error not appearing anymore, the scheduled jobs are not being fired either. When I try to send a bulk mailing, nothing happens even though the cronjob scrolls through /var/log/cron and no errors reported in any other log files. Bump!