# No cron runs have been recorded (CiviCRM 4.7.25 on Wordpress 4.8?)

Tags: wordpress, cron-job

I don't know how could I solve this problem. I have this problem from the beginning of installing. I read the other answers at this forum but they could;n solve my problem. 
would you please tell me how can I solve this error step by step?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please state the steps you have already tried for setting up cron on your server.

Comment: I read the below links solutions but they didn't work for me!!! https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9491/cron-not-running-system-error-after-update-to-4-7-1, https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10822/system-status-error-cron-not-running-after-update-to-4-7-4

Comment: Your question is too vague and adding three exclamation marks does not help clarify anything. Give facts and details. What type of hosting do you have? What did you do exactly to set up cron? Have you contacted your hosting provider for help with your crontab?

Comment: I have contacted my hosting provider and they asked what cron isn't running related to CiviCRM, and they could not help me unless they knew the name of the cron and I don't know about the name of corn. Also, I changed the version of CiviCRM but it doesn't work for me. and I changed cli.php from 0754 to 0755 but doesn't work!

Comment: I'll ask again. What did you do to set up cron on your server?

Comment: I am not sure about getting your question correctly or not so I add another pic to my question I hope it was your question answer

Comment: I install wp_cli and try to use code <em>$ /path/to/wp-cli \ --user=myusername \ --url=http://example.org \ --path=/var/www/example.org/ \ civicrm api job.execute auth=0</em> but I don't know what should I put on as user and path?
would you please help me regarding this one?

Answer (score 3):

From your second image, I see that you have not yet set up cron for CiviCRM. The first entry in your crontab executes the Wordpress job. A second entry is needed to execute the CiviCRM job.

Here are the instructions for doing so: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#choosing-a-method

Comment: I go to this site and  create new cron job but it doesn't work https://www.easycron.com/

Answer (score 0):

You've to put your wordpress admin username. and path is nothing but your website path. For instance if your site is in public_html - have to include the public_html path.